# Properly handle heavy double for loop with async function and promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, async-await, do-while

I'm new to async functions and promises in JavaScript. I would like to step through a double for loop while showing its progress. So far I cannot get it to update the progress, and seems to take a lot more time than the vanilla double for loop I had before, while remaining taxing (I get the spinning beach ball on this Mac). It only shows the progress at the very end.

```
async function render(autoZoomAndPan) {

    let zoom = setZoom * quality

    for(var x=0; x < renderSize.w; x++){

        for(var y=0; y < renderSize.h; y++){

            await draw(x,y,zoom)

            if(!autoZoomAndPan){
                let allLoops = renderSize.w * renderSize.h
                let currentLoops = x * y
                var percent = (currentLoops / allLoops) * 100 
                document.getElementById('debug1').innerHTML ="<h3>Processed:" + percent + "%</h3>";
            }


        }           
    }

}      

function draw(x,y,zoom){

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var i = 0                           
        var cx = -xCoord + x / zoom                 
        var cy = -yCoord + y / zoom                                        
        var zx = 0                          
        var zy = 0           


        do{                                 
            var xt = zx * zy;                                   
            zx = zx * zx - zy * zy + cx;                                    
            zy = zyMult * xt + cy;  

            i++;
        }               
        while(i < (palletteSize - 1) && (zx * zx + zy * zy) < (pixelSize * quality));                           

        context.beginPath();

        context.fillStyle = pallette[i]

        context.fillRect(x*pixelSize, y*pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize); 

        resolve('resolved');

    })

}     

render(false)
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that's async,..  But one idea, instead of `resolve('resolved')`,  make a simple async op by doing -> `setTimeout(() => resolve('resolved'), 1);`  This would then yield control back to the browers to give it chance to update it's UI.

Comment: I replaced "resolve('resolved')" with what you suggested, and it's way slower, but the progress is updated while it is drawing it one pixel at a time.

Comment: Yes, just resolve with the timeout less often,